# Adding a maximum date range to PHP array

Tags: php, date

how can I add a maximum date range of 3 months to the below PHP so that it will only let the user select a date range of 3 months when inputted?

```
public static function id_fes_start_date_field($vars) {
    $field = array(
        'label' => __('Start Date', 'ignitiondeck'),
        'value' => (isset($vars['project_start']) ? $vars['project_start'] : ''),
        'name' => 'project_start',
        'id' => 'project_start',
        'type' => 'text',
        'class' => 'required date',
        'wclass' => 'form-row half left'
    );
    return $field;
}

public static function id_fes_end_date_field($vars) {
    $field = array(
        'label' => __('End Date', 'ignitiondeck'),
        'value' => (isset($vars['project_end']) ? $vars['project_end'] : ''),
        'name' => 'project_end',
        'id' => 'project_end',
        'type' => 'text',
        'class' => 'required date',
        'wclass' => 'form-row half'
    );
    return $field;
}
```

I've read somethings about the jQuery datepicker but am a bit lost as how to implement it.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery datepicker would do great for you because it does front end validation. You would have to load the proper javascript library and then link it by the correct id or name. Look into that and loading the javascript with your form.

Otherwise, using only PHP, you would have to check whether the date selected is within your range when the data is submitted since PHP runs server side and responds to requests. Then you would either submit the data or return an error to the user and ask them to submit a valid date.

*edit. From the information you provided, there is not enough for me to quickly change and add form validation. Those are just two function, which we do not know how they are called or manipulated.